DC generator and armature reaction and interpole
The magnetic field produced by the interpoles opposes the armature reaction field and works to shift the MNA back toward its correct position. Therefore, the magnetic fields from both the interpoles and armature reaction should be nearly equal, implying that the EMFs induced by these fields in the shorted coil undergoing commutation should also be nearly equal and opposite.
The L di/dt voltage gets compensated by the interpoles during commutation. How exactly does this compensation occur?
If the armature reaction and interpoles generate magnetic fields of similar magnitude, how is it possible that the induced EMFs in the same coil are not equal?

An interpole just bends the magnetic field locally at the brush so that the short introduced by the brush (between commutator segments) doesn't have a significant voltage  and cause a significant arc at the brush.
